# How to fix 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch' error inside FOR loop

Tags: matlab

I've been getting this `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` error in matlab when trying to transpose a vector inside a `for` loop. I've checked other questions and solutions to no avail and any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
id = spikes.labels(:,1);
cl = id(spikes.labels(:,2) == 2); 


for i = 1:length(cl);
    ii = cl(i);
    indexSpike = find(spikes.assigns == ii);     
    Unit = spikes.unwrapped_times(indexSpike);    
    strcat('Unit', num2str(ii)) = Unit';
    save (strcat('Unit', num2str(ii), '.mat'), strcat('Unit', num2str(ii)));
end
```

In the second to last line inside the loop I need to transpose the vector called `Unit` and name it according to `ii`. 
This is where I get the error.

Comment: Well, `strcat('Unit', num2str(ii))` returns a string, why do you want to assign some value to a string rather than a variable? What exactly do you want to achieve on that line?

Comment: I'm trying to name a variable according to the value of ii. It should output something like: Unit12 = Unit'. How could I go about defining the string as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a structure array for this problem. Structure will have two properties name and value. Assign `strcat('Unit', num2str(ii))` to name and `Unit'` to value

```
units(ii).name = strcat('Unit', num2str(ii));
units(ii).value = Unit';
save (strcat('Unit', num2str(ii), '.mat'), Unit');
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. Much easier to use a struct! For anyone using the above code, I just edited the `save` line in order to save every file independently: `save(strcat(units(i).name, '.mat'), 'UnitData');`